# Make the Enter Key behave like the Tab Key in a JTable

Tags: java, jtable

The Enter Key on my JTable already goes horizontally from the first column to the last one, then to the next row using:

```
table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "selectNextColumnCell"); //To make it move horizontally
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true); //To save the edited value when focus is lost
```

The problem is that when editing I have to click Enter twice to go to the next column (first time to finish editing and second to move to next column), while tab does it in one click. How do I make the Enter behave like the Tab and move in one click to the next column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by overriding the DefaultTableModel's setValueAt method in the following way:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value,
            int rowIndex,
            int columnIndex) {
        super.setValueAt(value, rowIndex, columnIndex);
        ProductsT.setRowSelectionInterval(rowIndex, rowIndex);
        ProductsT.changeSelection(rowIndex, columnIndex + 1, false, false);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key's mapping before adding a new one for it.

Here is an example:

```
// remove default mapping.
table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), null);
// add new mapping.
table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "selectNextColumnCell");
```

Comment: Tried it but it's still not moving in a single click.